# Why my perceptron doesn't train well and produces bad results on test data?

Tags: python, numpy, perceptron

I am a newbie in Machine learning and I am writing a small code for Perceptron. This is the first time I am writing code in Python. 
I have four training data points (X). As they are used for supervised learning so, each data point has its corresponding correct output pair (D). I have implemented SGD and used generalized Delta rule (wij ← wij + α δixj). I have trained my perceptron 10,000 times (epochs= 10,000).
Although everything looks fine to me, I don't get the right results when I test it with test values. I need some suggestions so that I can improve my results on test data. P.S. How can I improve this code?

Code

```
import numpy as np 

def sigmoid(x):
return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))    

def Delta_SGD(W, X, D):
 N = 4
 for x in range(N):

    v1 = np.dot(X[x][0], W[0])
    v2 = np.dot(X[x][1], W[1])
    v3 = np.dot(X[x][2], W[2])
    #weighted sum
    V = v1+v2+v3

    #output of neuron
    y = sigmoid(V)

    #error 
    e = D[x] - y

    #derivative of sigmoid(y)
    delta = (y)*(1-y)*e

    #Delta rule
    DW = alpha*delta*X[x]

    #updated weights
    W[0] = W[0] + DW[0]
    W[1] = W[1] + DW[1]
    W[2] = W[2] + DW[2]

return W

#input data points
X = np.array([ [0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1] ])

#Correct output pairs
D = np.array([[0,0,1,1]]).T

#learning rate
alpha = 0.9

#random weights
W =  2*np.random.random((3,1)) - 1

#10000 epochs
for epoch in range(10000):
 W = Delta_SGD(W, X, D)
 print(epoch)

#Final weights after all epochs
print("Final weights are \n", W)

#testing network
N = 4
for x in range(N):

 v1 = np.dot(X[x][0], W[0])
 v2 = np.dot(X[x][1], W[1])
 v3 = np.dot(X[x][2], W[2])

 V = v1+v2+v3
 y = sigmoid(V)
 print("output of neuron is \n ", y)
```

Comment: your training data consists of only 4 samples?

Comment: yes only four samples as its a basic perceptron.

Comment: without looking at your code you don't have enough samples, in particular for 10,000 steps. there is only so much to learn from four samples... you'd have a better chance with 10,000 samples and 4 epochs

Comment: Everything is right my friend. show us your test data. maybe that is the problem. I tried your code and it works.

Comment: @KasraManshaei Thanks it's working perfectly now. The test data I used is the same as the input as u can see in the above code.

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan perfect! I wanted to mention some points about it (for instance the mistake you have in testing concept). As your question is solved I can give you some tips as the answer. If you like.

Comment: @KasraManshaei sure please give me tips and how can I improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points about the whole thing

1. You did not **test** yet. The point behind the training process is to make machine able to learn from the data **conditioned on** the ability of generalizing this to predicting samples which it has not seen before. Otherwise, the good training is actually [overfitting](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/9760/8878). So here you trained on X and you need to create new samples and check the result to really call it testing (this is an introductory explanation).
2. Machine Learning is about [features](https://www.experfy.com/training/courses/feature-engineering-in-machine-learning) a lot! Playing with features and cleaning, modifying and filtering them is a key point. In your example, the last dimension of your 3d data is always 1. Does it distinguish anything? (in my course you get a complete explanation of this in the Lecture 2). So that feature (dimenstion, element of the vector) can/should be removed. To better understanding, imagine your 3d spread of the data. The *z* axis is always 1 which means the topology of points is what you see in *x-y* plain. So use only that one.

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely right. I just did it for purpose and that is that I wanted to learn how 3 inputs can be used to input a single neuron. Otherwise, if I just remove the third column I can tweak these inputs for the OR and AND problems etc. And for the first point, I totally agree but I am learning step by step :) BTW i'll look into your course.

Comment: As a starter your understanding and code are both very elegant! Good Luck my friend :)